# I got net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays not found

Tags: blackberry, java-me

when I run my application in blackberry that time it fire error

`net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays  not found`

Comment: What SDK are you targeting vs OS on the simulator/device?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are developing your app using target lower than OS 4.6 & `net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays` is supported since from OS 4.6